# Comparing data frames with a level of error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have two dataframes as

**df_schematic**

```
  layer     x          y
0   18  -10850.0    -6550.0
1   18  -10850.0    -5750.0
2   18  -10950.0    -5850.0
3   18  -10950.0    -5450.0
4   31  -10850.0    -5350.0
5   14  -10850.0    -4950.0
6   17    2945.5     6550.0

2278 rows × 3 columns
```

**df_report**

```
  layer  x        y
0   18  9161.19 -3106.42
1   18  9141.51 -3185.38
2   18  9023.40 -3185.38
3   18  9003.71 -3106.42
4   18  8800.20 -2840.65
5   17   2945.8  6549.6

2216 rows × 3 columns
```

i am trying to compare df_schematic with the report and find out any missing or irregular values among the report. The main problem is the level of tolerance we can have for a coordinate. 
For example:

```
17 2945.5 6550.0
```

and

```
17 2945.8 6549.6
```

are clearly not equal but they should be passed as a correct entry as the error level is +/-0.5.
Is there any way to find out the missing values and while keeping the tolerance in mind.

Comment: We use the data you provide to run our code on. So, you should include your 'similar' data in both the data-frames & show us the kind of output you need.

Comment: i dont get what you are trying to imply the data in the frame is the actual data that is needed to be compared among each other with a level of error resistance

Comment: what i meant was `17 2945.5 6550.0` is not in the first df & `17 2945.8 6549.6` is not in the 2nd df. Anyway,  what would be the output of the 2 data frames you have put?

Comment: oh sorry about that , well all the missing values that were present in the df_schematic but are missing from df_report into a separate data frame, i will try to improve my question , thanks

Comment: does the column `layer` matter or not? for example if the first df has `18  -10850.0    -6550.0` and the second df has `21  -10850.0    -6550.0` (only layer column is different). is it considered same or not?

Comment: yes layer matters , tolerance will only come in play when layer of the two coordinates is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make some experiments with *np.isclose*.

I mean the following scenario:

- Write a function, say *isClose*, comparing one pair of coordinates (x1, y1) with
  another pair (x2, y2), from 2 source rows, something like
  `np.isclose(x1, x2, atol=0.5) & np.isclose(y1, y2, atol=0.5)`.
- Taking a row from *df_schematic* as a "base point":

  - find in *df_report* all rows with **exactly** equal value of *layer*,
  - for each such row check *isClose* for *x* and *y* coordinates from both rows,
    until you find one where this function returns *True*.
- Repeat this procedure for each row from *df_schematic*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i was certainly unaware of the np.isclose() @Valdi_Bo